# How to change angular material sort icon

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, angular-material2

I need to change default arrow icon from angular material matSort to a custom arrow.

The current code

```
 <mat-table #table [dataSource]="source" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" [matSortActive]="sort.active" [matSortDirection]="sort.direction">
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: It isn't possible to change that icon because it's technically not an icon - just line-shaped divs layed out to look like an arrow. You would have to add your own icons to the column headers and manage sorting and icon visibility yourself.

Comment: `sortData($e) { $e.direction === 'asc'? (this.icon = 'myIcon') : (this.icon= 'myDescIcon') }``___` `<mat-icon  [maticon]="icon" class="mr2"></mat-icon>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow[style] {

  // Hide default arrow stem
  .mat-sort-header-stem {
    display: none;
  }
  .mat-sort-header-indicator {
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;

    // Hide default arrow as its composed of left, right and middle
    .mat-sort-header-pointer-left, .mat-sort-header-pointer-right, .mat-sort-header-pointer-middle  {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

// My custom ascending arrow
[aria-sort="ascending"] {
  ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {
      &::before {
        content: "\2191";
        top: -1.6em;
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
  }
}

// My custom descending arrow
[aria-sort="descending"] {
  ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {
      &::before {
        content: "\2193";
        top: -2.4em;
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add more context either to the answer itself or as comments inside the code blocks to make it more obvious what's happening. Simply posting blocks of code doesn't usually provide the context needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Added comments. Hope it helps.

Comment: Best solution IMHO, if you want it across all your site, put in you main stlye and remove the ng-deep

Comment: Seems this has been deprecated

Comment: The problem with this code is, on hover, it will show blank instead of greyed out icon.

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this.
app.component.ts

import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}


app.component.css

    .mat-sort-header-stem {
    height: 3px !important;
    width: 10px !important;
    transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-pointer-left, .mat-sort-header-pointer-right {
    width: 7px !important;
    height: 3px !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-pointer-middle{
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Artur

You can try this

```css
[aria-sort='ascending'] {
  ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow{
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {
      &::before{
        font: normal normal normal 1.1rem/1 FontAwesome;
        content: "\f0d7";
        position: absolute;
        top: .2rem;
      }
    }
  }
}

[aria-sort='descending'] {
  ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow { 
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {
      &::before{
        font: normal normal normal 1.1rem/1 FontAwesome;
        content: "\f0d8";
        position: absolute;
        top: -.9rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that is the way that I made it

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (dblclick)="sortData(column.field)"> {{ column.title }}<mat-icon *ngIf="sort.active==column.field" style="font-size:11pt;color:dimgray;font-weight: 700;padding-left:5px">{{sort.direction=="asc"?"arrow_upward":"arrow_downward"}}</mat-icon></mat-header-cell>
```

---

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="sort.active==column.field" style="font-size:11pt;color:dimgray;font-weight: 700;padding-left:5px">{{sort.direction=="asc"?"arrow_upward":"arrow_downward"}}</mat-icon>**
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Amuthan 's answer which hides the default display.  This code must reside in the global css. It displays carets instead of arrows:

```css
/* in global css document: */
/* this makes it so that sort header arrow is always shown: */
.mat-sort-header-arrow.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-arrowPosition {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    color: blue;
    
  }
/* Hide the default sort arrow display: */
.mat-sort-header-stem {
    display: none  !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-pointer-left, .mat-sort-header-pointer-right {
    display: none  !important;
}
.mat-sort-header-pointer-middle{
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}
/* show two carets on top of each other when not sorted takes place: */
    .mat-sort-header-arrow {
         .mat-sort-header-indicator {
           &::before {
             content: "<>"; 
             position: absolute;
             opacity: 1 !important;
             color:  blue !important;
             font-size: 1.2em;
             font-weight: bold;
             transform: translate(-10%, 20%)   rotate(90deg) !important;
           }
         }
       }

/* show ascending caret when sorted ascending:*/
[aria-sort="ascending"] {
 .mat-sort-header-arrow {
      .mat-sort-header-indicator {
        &::before {
          content: "<"; 
          position: absolute;
          color:  blue !important;
          opacity: 1 !important;
          font-size: 1.2em;
          font-weight: bold;
          transform: translate(0,0) rotate(90deg) !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
 /* show descending caret when sorted descending: */
  [aria-sort="descending"] {
.mat-sort-header-arrow {
      .mat-sort-header-indicator {
        &::before {
          content: ">";
          position: absolute;
          color:  blue !important;
          opacity: 1 !important;
          font-size: 1.2em;
          font-weight: bold;
          transform: translate(0,-10%) rotate(90deg) !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the result: [Table header with carets for sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMXDz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @amuthan solution I came up with this, it's the same arrow as dropdown uses, and it also shows up when hovering:

```
.mat-sort-header-arrow[style] {
  .mat-sort-header-stem {
    display: none;
  }
  .mat-sort-header-indicator {
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;

    .mat-sort-header-pointer-left, .mat-sort-header-pointer-right, .mat-sort-header-pointer-middle  {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
.mat-sort-header-indicator {
  &::before {
    content: "";
    top: 0.1em;
    position: absolute;
    color: $primary;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid;
    margin: 0 4px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
}


[aria-sort="ascending"] {
  .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {
      &::before {
        top: 0.1em;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        opacity: 1;

      }
    }
  }
}

[aria-sort="descending"] {
  .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {
      &::before {
        top: -0.6em;
        transform: rotate(0);
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```