# Creating custom arrow in Angular Material sort header

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am creating Angular 5 project and I wanted to create custom sort icon in sort header to achieve this effect https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-up?style=solid. I don't want to have this default arrow.

I tried to change css style, but it seems not to work. Or maybe is there any way to replace this icon by custom using JS?

```
::ng-deep  {

    .cdk-visually-hidden {
        border: 0;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
    }

    .mat-sort-header-stem {
        background: none;
        display: none !important;
    }

    .mat-sort-header-container {
        position: relative;
    }
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {

      transform: translateY(0px) !important;
    }

    .mat-sort-header-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        transform: translateY(0%) !important;
    }


  }
```

Thank for any suggestions.

Edit.

If someone has this problem, I solved it by adding custom directive to mat-sort-header element. I also passed to directive the sort direction (ASC or DESC). Finally based on the direction I customized my sort icon using pure CSS.

Comment: try this click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54703914/7797727) mat-sort icon change like caret-up

Answer (score 1):

see if this help you

```css
.triangle {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2em auto;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866);
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
}

.triangle:before {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 20% 53%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(-24%);
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: '';
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
}

.triangle:after {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 53% 20%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) skewX(-30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(24%);
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: '';
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion was helpful, but I solved it in a different way. I had to add the directive to sorting button in order to detect sorting direction. After that I styled the button using CSS. Thanks for you answer anyway.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, can you give more dtails of your solution please?