# Change mat-sort-header ascending/descending icon to custom like font-awesome caret-down/caret-up Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, font-awesome, mat-table

Trying to Change mat-sort-header default ascending/descending icon to custom icon(i.e fontawesome caret-down) using Angular8/"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",

Not a great css developer searched through various links [How to change angular material sort icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634592/how-to-change-angular-material-sort-icon)
[Creating custom arrow in Angular Material sort header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648308/creating-custom-arrow-in-angular-material-sort-header) Didn't fit my scenario.

[image]

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make `display: none` to other icons that are used for default icon. then use add content as CSS before selector and use content to show your font awesome icon.

```
[aria-sort="descending"] {
  ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    .mat-sort-header-indicator {
      &::before {
        content: "<i class='fa fa-caret-down'>...</i>";
        top: -1.0em;
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-table-custom-sort-icon)

Comment: This is broken in your example and in angular 9. Needs an update

Comment: I removed "::ng-deep" and it works very well now with Angular 16.